# Azure Functions Filter functionality general availability

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I've noticed that Azure Functions have a Filter functionality which is described here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters. 
The article is from November 2017 and states that the feature is in preview.

I want to use this functionality in a project for error handling. The deadline for it is in June. My question is the following.

Does anybody know if there is a certainty that this functionality will be ready before June ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **no**.

Just a bit longer answer: unfortunately there are no guarantees as far as roadmap goes, since the roadmap might be subject to change based on a lot of factors.

I think the issue you [raised at GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2134) might give you an insider answer, but guarantees will most probably not be given.

Comment: is there a public roadmap for Azure features, for example like they publish for TFS/Azure Devops?

Comment: There's [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/) which lets you "Learn about important Azure product updates, roadmap, and announcements. Subscribe to notifications to stay informed."